# Android Listview ArrayAdapter Fade In/Out when element added/removed

Tags: android, listview, animation, adapter

Using an `ArrayAdapter` and an Android `Listview`, I would like to be able to automatically start an animation with each row of the Listview, when the element is added or removed from my `ArrayList`.

I found a lot of tutorials, but they work with a `onItemClickListener`,
so the animation is started when the user clicks on a row.
In my case, rows are added programmatically, and might be deleted anytime by my app. I can't find the easiest way to access the `view` related to the ArrayList element I am dealing with.

I would like the animations to be quite long (30 seconds), so even if the view isn't currently visible on the `listview`, I would like the animation to be engaged when the user will scroll to the `view`.

Comment: That will be easier if you switch to `RecyclerView`, which has [a whole system set up for this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have anything I could read to learn how to do what I want ? Will my adapter work with a RecyclerView ?

Comment: `RecyclerView` has its own `RecyclerView.Adapter`, which is reminiscent of `BaseAdapter` but not quite identical. There is [at least one library of canned animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators). Beyond that, use a search engine and search on `recyclerview itemanimator fade` or something.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you

Comment: Answer my post, so I can accept it :)

Comment: I did not answer the question as written. I merely pointed you in a different direction. You might consider answering the question yourself, if you worked out a solution.